# Rendertarget.SavetoXXX kills graphics device

Tags: c#, ios, image, xamarin.ios, monogame

So I am trying to save to a png/or jpeg yet when I run these methods nothing draws anymore. It is stuck on what ever frame was drawn before the call.

This is on IOS by the way.

So I set the graphics device to a rendertarget 
draw 
bring it back to null 
then execute the savetopng method

if I comment out the savetopng it works

I am using the latest stable monogame build(2.5.1 I think?) 
please help having the user save a image is vital to my game!

```
renderTarget = new RenderTarget2D( graphics.GraphicsDevice, graphics.GraphicsDevice.PresentationParameters.BackBufferHeight, graphics.GraphicsDevice.PresentationParameters.BackBufferWidth);
graphics.GraphicsDevice.SetRenderTarget(renderTarget); 
Draw(new GameTime()); 
graphics.GraphicsDevice.SetRenderTarget(null);
renderTarget.SaveAsPng(File.Create(Environment.GetFolderPath (Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal) + "/test.png"),renderTarget.Width,renderTarget.Height);
```

Comment: renderTarget = new RenderTarget2D(

graphics.GraphicsDevice,

graphics.GraphicsDevice.PresentationParameters.BackBufferHeight,

graphics.GraphicsDevice.PresentationParameters.BackBufferWidth);

graphics.GraphicsDevice.SetRenderTarget(renderTarget);

                   
 Draw(new GameTime());

                   graphics.GraphicsDevice.SetRenderTarget(null);

renderTarget.SaveAsPng(File.Create(Environment.GetFolderPath (Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal) + "/test.png"),renderTarget.Width,renderTarget.Height);

Comment: There should be an error message in the console, do you see one?

Comment: I see no error or warning message. The game is still running, the update function is being called but the graphics device or spritebatch is frozen.

Answer (score 0):

There's just not great RenderTarget suppport on iOS right now. There are a couple of tickets in to fix it, but the people working on the iOS side of things have been busy on other things.

I'm not sure about setting different rendertargets, but I'm pretty sure that SaveToPng hasn't been fully implemented on iOS.